# How to align two neighboring columns of data along their vertical common border?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I am relatively new to LaTeX (using it since early 2016), and making my Cv I came across a difficulty. I have written the following code in the CV tex file:

```
\begin{tabular}{ @{} >{\bfseries}l @{\hspace{1ex}} l }
John Ingham\\
Birth Date &: 2 August, 1993 \\
Current Residential Address &:18 Cambridge St.\\
Contact &: 694 147 5892\\
\end{tabular}
```

which produces something like this:

[image]

I would like to create a blank column along the : symbols so that the words date, address, contact be right aligned and their respective data on the right column be left aligned, (both columns in equal distances from the : symbols) around the : symbols. Could someone please help with this?

Comment: Welcome To  TeX SX! Could you post a *full* compilable code?

Comment: for start change `Current Residential Address &:18 Cambridge St.\\` to `Current Residential Address &: 18 Cambridge St.\\` (observe space after semicolon). for more we need complete small document.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of manually inserting colons, add `@{ ~:~ }` to the column setup so that it automatically inserts the colons with with some spacing around. You can replace `~`s with any spacing command, of course.

```
\begin{tabular}{ @{} >{\bfseries}l @{ ~:~ } l }
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\bfseries John Ingham}  \\
Birth Date                  & 2 August, 1993  \\
Current Residential Address & 18 Cambridge St.\\
Contact                     & 694 147 5892    \\
\end{tabular}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}\usepackage{multirow, makecell}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\bfseries}r @{\hspace{1ex}:\hspace{1ex}} l@{}}
  \multicolumn{2}{@{}>{\bfseries}l@{}}{John Ingham} \\
  Birth Date & 2 August, 1993 \\
  Current Residential Address & 18 Cambridge St. \\
  Contact & 694 147 5892 \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the LaTeX codes mentioned here with direct usage of `\halign`. The code (especially the columns declaration) looks more simple.

```
\halign{\hfil\bf#\unskip&~:~#\hfil\cr
  John Ingham\hfill\ \cr
  Birth Date & 2 August, 1993 \cr
  Current Residential Address & 18 Cambridge St.\cr
  Contact & 694 147 5892\cr
}

\bye
```